# carry out operation on pandas column using an IF statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [77000581079,77000458432,77000458433,77000458434,77000691973], "Code": ['FO07930', 'FO73597','FO03177','FO73596','FOZZZZZ']})
```

I want to check the value of each row in column `Code` to see if it matches str `FOZZZZ`

If the operation is `False` then I would like to `concatenate` `Id` value to `Code` value

So the expected output will be:

```
    Id          Code
0   77000581079 FO0793077000581079
1   77000458432 FO7359777000458432
2   77000458433 FO0317777000458433
3   77000458434 FO7359677000458434
4   77000691973 FOZZZZZ
```

Ive tried

```
df['Id'] = df['Id'].astype(str)
for x in df['Id']:
    if x == 'FOZZZZ':
     pass
else:
    df['Id']+df['Code']
```

Which I thought would run over each row in Column `Code` to check if it is `=`
to `'FOZZZZ'` if not then `concatenate` the columns but no joy..

Comment: `df['Id'] = df['Id']+df['Code']` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Code']!='FOZZZZZ', 'Code'] = df['Code'] + df['Id'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.Series.where` with `eq`:

```
s = df["Code"]
df["Code"] = s.where(s.eq("FOZZZZZ"), s + df["Id"].astype(str))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Code           Id
0  FO0793077000581079  77000581079
1  FO7359777000458432  77000458432
2  FO0317777000458433  77000458433
3  FO7359677000458434  77000458434
4             FOZZZZZ  77000691973
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `np.where(condition, solution if condition is true, solution if condition is false)`. Use `.isin(to check)` if `FOZZZZZ` exists and reverse using `~` to build a boolean query to be used as condition.

```
df['Code']=np.where(~df['Code'].isin(['FOZZZZZ']), df.Id.astype(str)+df.Code,df.Code)

     Id                Code
0  77000581079  77000581079FO07930
1  77000458432  77000458432FO73597
2  77000458433  77000458433FO03177
3  77000458434  77000458434FO73596
4  77000691973             FOZZZZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try using `loc`:

```
df['Code'] = df['Code'] + df['Id'].astype(str)
df.loc[df['Code'].str.contains('FOZZZZZ'), 'Code'] = 'FOZZZZZ'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Code           Id
0  FO0793077000581079  77000581079
1  FO7359777000458432  77000458432
2  FO0317777000458433  77000458433
3  FO7359677000458434  77000458434
4             FOZZZZZ  77000691973
```